# <span> does not color the text between new paragraphs

Tags: html, css

My HTML code is:

```
 <p> Marium, Sameen and Mubashir are not working. ok </p> <p> THIS IS NEW LINE </p> This is result 2 <p> Marium, Sameen and Mubashir are not working. <span class=ins>ok </p> <p> THIS IS NEW LINE</span> </p>
```

And my CSS is:

```
 span.ins { color: green; display:inline;}  
 span.del { color:red;  text-decoration:line-through; display:inline;}
```

It colors the portion that is before the next `<p>` tag. That is "ok". But it does not color "THIS IS NEW LINE".

What could be the solution to it? I cannot use div as it changes the line itself. I don't want the line to be changed.

Comment: Any reason you're using class names rather than the ins and del elements?

Comment: Your HTML nesting is extremely off and invalid. And btw, no need to add `display: inline;` to `<span>`. It's the default.

Comment: @BoltClock I guess he's the `<div class="headline">` type of guy.

Comment: Your html formatting is wrong.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/245sttt1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct HTML is:

```css
span.ins {
  color: green;
  display: inline;
}
span.del {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p>Marium, Sameen and Mubashir are not working. ok</p>
<p>THIS IS NEW LINE</p>
This is result 2
<p>Marium, Sameen and Mubashir are not working. <span class="ins">ok </span>
</p>
<p><span class="ins">THIS IS NEW LINE</span>
</p>
```

Comment: This is auto formatting done by a code. "ok" is a part of previous paragraph and it has been newly inserted, so it is colored green and then "THIS IS NEW LINE" is also newly inserted and it is of different paragraph

Comment: @MariumMalik this is the formatting I understand from your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Your html is invalid use following HTML structure of `HTML snippet` then your css will work:

```css
span.ins { color: green; display:inline;}  
span.del { color:red;  text-decoration:line-through; display:inline;}
```

```html
<p> Marium, Sameen and Mubashir are not working. ok </p> 
<p> THIS IS NEW LINE </p> This is result 2 
<p> Marium, Sameen and Mubashir are not working.</p>
<p><span class=ins>ok THIS IS NEW LINE</span></p>
```

[**Jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ttmLx2ab/)

Comment: This is auto formatting done by a code. "ok" is a part of previous paragraph and it has been newly inserted, so it is colored green and then "THIS IS NEW LINE" is also newly inserted and it is of different paragraph

Comment: Which IDE you are using??

Answer (score 0):

There is Nothing wrong in your css but slight change in HTML.

Instead of

```
<span class=ins>ok </p> <p> THIS IS NEW LINE</span></p>
```

Do

```
</p><span class=ins>ok  <p> THIS IS NEW LINE </p></span>
```

there is complete code

```
<p> Marium, Sameen and Mubashir are not working. ok </p>
<p> THIS IS NEW LINE </p> This is result 2
<p> Marium, Sameen and Mubashir are not working.</p>
<span class=ins>ok  
<p> THIS IS NEW LINE </p></span>
```